# React Structure: Avoiding multiple ternary operators

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Within a component I'm attempting to "hide" and "show" elements as a user clicks through content. I was told ternary operators are the way to do this. However now it's getting far more complicated / messy due to nested ternary operators.

Is this the correct approach in React or is there a better way?

Example:

```
const [compltedWaveOne, setcompltedWaveOne] = useState(false);
const [compltedWaveTwo, setcompltedWaveTwo] = useState(false);
const [compltedWaveThree, setcompltedWaveThree] = useState(false);
const [compltedWaveFour, setcompltedWaveFour] = useState(false);
   
  {compltedWaveOne ?
  ...Large amount of content 
  : //else 
  ...Large amount of content 
  }

  ... Now I need more content here if completedWaveTwo is true etc. Also need to hide the other content
```

Comment: Maybe create a separate component for every wave?

Comment: Seemed like overkill but maybe thats the right call!

Comment: There's not really enough context to know what's going on in the snippet. It sounds like there's at least one missing abstraction here, e.g., a directed series of events, each showing its own content--it's a state machine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ternary operators are great IMO, but they get messy once you start nesting. That is why you wanna do something like this:

   ```js
   if(compltedWaveOne) {
     return ([CONTENT]) // you can use your ternary op. here
   } else {
     return ([CONTENT])
   }
   ```
2. I would recommend better naming conventions rather than `compltedWaveOne`
3. Your `useState` is not valid since you name both variables the same.

   Stick to this type of convention:

   ```js
   const [state, setState] = useState()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using multiple state, you could simply use an array and map with respect to the component.

```
const WavesComponents = [Wave1, Wave2, Wave3, Wave4, Wave5];

function _App() {
  const [waves, setCompletedWaves] = useState([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);

  function toggleCompletion(idx) {
    setCompletedWaves(prev => {
      prev.slice();
      prev[idx] = !prev[idx];
      return prev;
    });
  }

  const WaveComponent = WavesComponents[waves];
  return <WaveComponent data={} />;
}
```